# Proving question (Differentiation)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that $y=\tan (x+\frac{\pi}{4})+1$, show that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2y(\frac{dy}{dx}$).

I got $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sec^2 (\frac{\pi}{4}+x)$ but I don't know how to proceed.

P/s: The question states that you cannot find the first and second derivative then substitute to the original equation.

Comment: If you do what is, mysteriously, forbidden, you will find that the equality does not hold.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=tan\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=sec^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
Observe that
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(y-1)^2+1$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2(y-1)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Maybe there's a slight mistake in what you are trying to prove.